# Whether the word "yourself" is used as an object pronoun or not?

Tags: pronouns, objects

> You'll have to explain **yourself** more clearly.

In this sentence, I'd like to know whether the word "yourself" is used as an object pronoun or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can explain why you are asking this question you can get a better answer. Are you unclear what "object" means, or "pronoun"?

Comment: Not being a native speaker, I'm sometimes confused with some words. Please explain it to me. I don't want down votes.

Comment: **Yourself** is a _reflexive_ pronoun. This is explained in most books on English grammar. You can learn more at this [link](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-reflexive.htm).

Comment: @theinlwin Do you know what a _reflexive pronoun_ is in English?